# C - Why do I keep printing out the Memory Address instead of the value in the array

Tags: c, arrays

I am having trouble printing out the values stored in the array. It seems to be printing out the memory address instead. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void getMatrix(int x, int y);
void printMatrix(int arr[], int x, int y);
int product(int arr1[], int arr2[]);

int main(void){

 //Variables that will store matrix size
 int m, n, o, p;

 //Prompt user for size of Matrix A
 printf("Enter the rows and columns of Matrix A with space in between: ");

 //Read input
 scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

 //Prompt user for the size of Matrix B
 printf("Enter the rows and columns of Matrix B with space in between: ");

 //Read input
 scanf("%d %d", &o, &p);

 //Seed RND Generator
 srand(time(NULL));

 //Check input
 if(n != o){
  while(n != o){
   printf("Matrix Sizes are not valid. Please enter valid sizes for the Matrices: ");
   scanf("%d %d %d %d", &m, &n, &o, &p);
  }
 } 

 //Function Calls
 printf("Matrix 1:\n");
 getMatrix(m, n);
 printf("\nMatrix 2:\n");
 getMatrix(o, p);
}

void getMatrix(int x, int y){

 //Counter
 int c;

 //Size Declaration
 int size = x * y;

 //Array Declaration
 int arr[size];

 for(c = 0; c < size; c++){
  arr[c] = rand()%10;
 }

 printMatrix(arr[size], x, y);
}

void printMatrix(int arr[], int x, int y){

 //Counters
 int i, j;

 for(i = 0; i < y; i++){
  printf("\n");
  for(j = 0; j < x; j++){
   printf("%d ", arr[j]);
  }
 }
}
```

So basically this code is supposed to take in input and create a variable length array and its supposed to store random numbers in a 1 dimensional array and then they have to be printed out in the form of a 2d array or a matrix. I feel there might be something wrong with the parameters of the `printMatrix` function or when passing the array obtained in the `getMatrix` function. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: Thank you all for the help. I didn't even think about using this as a solution. But it works now and prints out the numbers that it is supposed to. Thanks again

Comment: i am sure the compiler is complaining at you and you are ignoring its complaint, its trying to be helpful. Its complaining on this line `printMatrix(arr[size],...`

Comment: try changing `printMatrix(arr[size], x, y);` to `printMatrix(arr, x, y);`

Comment: You should get an error for the line `printMatrix(arr[size], x, y);` . If you don't then the first thing to do is adjust your compiler settings until you do get an error.  Then fix the error.

Comment: In `getMatrix()`: `printMatrix(arr[size], x, y);` --> `printMatrix(arr, x, y);`, and in `printMatrix()`: `printf("%d ", arr[j]);` --> `printf("%d ", arr[i * x + j]);`

Comment: I've tried using 'printMatrix(&arr[size], x, y);' instead of just the 'arr[size]' and that does eliminate all compiler notes and errors but it still does not print out the random numbers that are in the array

Comment: `&arr[size]` gets the address of where the first value *outside* of `arr` would be.

Comment: Btw, with some small adjustments you could just use 2D arrays instead of faking it by indexing a 1D array with row * width + col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration

```
int arr[size];
```

says that `arr` is an array of `size` `int`s.  Thus,

```
printMatrix( arr[size], x, y );
```

passes the *value* that happens to be where the first `int` *just outside* `arr` would be for the first argument, which the function interprets to be the address of the array to be printed.

Also, note that `printMatrix` keeps printing the first row again and again, as opposed to each successive row.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies with this line of code:

```
printMatrix(arr[size], x, y);
```

It should be

```
printMatrix(arr, x, y);
```

The printMatrix function expects an array, but in your code you pass an element from the array.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in the following line:

```
printMatrix(arr[size], x, y);
```

Is invoking undefined behavior. Since you have declared your array to be `arr[size]`, the counter of your array must range from `0` to `size - 1`.

When you are trying to pass `arr[size]`, rather than passing the whole array (which, judging form the program, is what you want it to do), you pass `arr` at element *size*, which is one index out of bounds.

Going into a bit more technical explaination of why this happens, the memory space that is right after the block allocated for `arr` must be empty, so you don't get segmentation fault, and instead, you get the address of that out-of-bound element. However, if it was *filled up*, then that would have caused a segmentation fault, and would have resulted in a runtime error.

To pass `arr`, you need to remove the index specifier:

```
printMatrix(arr, x, y);
```